# How to restric shown items in angular 2 ng2-tag-input

Tags: angular

i want to show limited items on tag input.  i tried maxItems - [?number] but it is used to restrict maximum entered items

Comment: Mohamed Rafeeq, please [edit] your question to add helpful explanation, instead of hiding it in a comment to an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `limitItemsTo - [?number]`

Hope this helps..

Comment: It is not working because it is used to Number of items to display in the autocomplete drop down.

Comment: Yes u are right. Can you rephrase ur question and explain in details so that i can help you.

Comment: while i am enter a value it is shown like button in tag input box.  if i enter 10 items one by one, then 10 items will be shown in tag input box.  But i don't want to show 10 items instead i want to show last entered 3 items.

Comment: @IrfanPathan Please try to write more assertive answers. Starting with "Try..." makes this look more like a clarification question, which should be a comment. You will get the commenting privilege soon if you continue participating as helpfully as you did. But please wait for it. This kind of tentative answer is more confusing than helpful for future users. (And you would not quote the 50 rep rule in an answer and then immediatly break it, would you? That would get deleted by a moderator quite quickly... ;-) )